# Why this operational amplifier is saturated?

Tags: circuit-analysis, saturation, operational-amplifier

my problem is that in this circuit:

[image]

Where \$\pm V_{cc} =\pm 15V, R1=1k\Omega, R2= 10k\Omega\$, if I introduce a signal like: \$ v_i(t) = 2 \cos{(2\pi 1000 t)}\$, the output voltaje is this:

[image]

Where the green line is the input and the red one the output. The problem is that although the O.A. is working between \$\pm 15V\$, the output signal is saturated at 4V approximately and I don't know why that happens.

The netlist of Pspice is this:

[image]

Moreover, I went to the laboratory and the O.A. *ua741* was also saturated with that input signal.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If that's a simulation then the 10kO (ten-k-oh rather than ten-k-zero) might be a problem. Try removing the 'O'. If it is a simulation then your question should make it clear and state the software being used. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor good catch, that could be the issue.  Looks like PSPICE to me from the output graph.

Comment: The 'O' isn't the problem. I can remove it, but the simulation it's still the same.

Comment: post your spice netlist

Comment: Ok, and I have added a comment because the issue is not the Pspice simulation, but the fact that the O.A. is saturated and I don't know why

Comment: Yes it does but his equation and text is 2 volts

Comment: I count 4 opamps in the netlist. Is it possible for you to create a separate netlist that actually reflects your lab arrangement so that we don't have to guess?

Comment: My PSpice 9.1  netlist look like this 


R_R1         0 $N_0001  1k  
R_R2         $N_0001 vo  10k  
V_V3         vi 0 DC 0 AC 0
+SIN 0 2 1k 0 0 0
V_V1         Vcc 0 DC 15  
X_U1         vi $N_0001 Vcc -Vcc vo uA741
V_V2         0 -Vcc DC 15  
R_RL         vo 0  10k

Comment: And everything works as expected.

Comment: Mine is:$$\begin{array}{l}\text{XU1 VP VM Vcc Vee VOUT UA741}\\
\text{R1 VOUT VM 10k}\\
\text{R2 0 VOUT 10k}\\
\text{R3 VM 0 1k}\\
\text{V1 VP 0 SINE(0 1 1k)}\\
\text{V99 Vcc 0 15}\\
\text{V98 0 Vee 15}\end{array}$$
And it also works as expected.

Comment: Your input voltage can´t be greater than 2V from your input signal. But in the graph it shows 1v peak. Something is missing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is a bad question, the netlist doesn't resemble the schematic and the pictures posted are not those of the netlist or description. The OP mentions a 2Vpp voltage source in the post, the netlist does not reflect that. The circuit posted is not that of the netlist. Fix your discrepancies and reopen the question

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your possible syntax * 
errors, you have a noninverting gain of 1+10 times the input peak  of 2 V, Which should result in +/-22 Vp but cannot.

If your R values 100R* are too small, then the internal current limiter will limit the output voltage. I-max is 40mA

You should allow the output to keep away from the supply rails by the amount given in the data sheet which may be 2 V in your case.

Comment: Input peak looks like 1 volt to me.

Comment: Looks like 2V in the actual equation of the question

Comment: Firtsly, sorry about my syntax,but English is not my mother tongue. Apart form that, I think that the saturation is produced due to the value of the load resistance. For example, if I place a 100 ohms resistance, theoretically vo=22V, which implicates a current of 220mA. However, the maximum output current of the O.A is 20mA, which means an output voltage of 2V.

Comment: That is correct if you are using typical values

Comment: By now I hope are reading I-max and not I-typ